# How to automatically enter brackets on autocomplete?

Tags: atom-editor

Whenever I use the autocomplete for atom it doesn't include the brackets. For example if i start typing "print" I hit enter and it enters print but doesn't include the brackets.

Comment: Which language are we talking about?

Comment: In case if you use autocomplete-python -- it's impossible to predict when you want to actually *call* a function, or just referencing it. Thus automatically appending a bracket seems like wrong behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The default [Python snippets](https://github.com/atom/language-python) only supports the `print` keyword, not the `print()` function. Since I haven't found another package that does, you're problably best off adding a snippet (Atom > Open Your Snippets) such as:

```
'.source.python':
  'print()':
    'prefix': 'print-function'
    'body': 'print($1)'
```

The prefix will trigger the snippet defined in the body, in case prefer to call it differently.

Comment: Note: As of Atom 1.10, local snippets are now Atom > Snippets...  Also, you will need to do something like a Window:Reload to get the new snippet to show up.